# Qt QListView rendering items as a queue of squares

Tags: qt

I have a list of items that I would like to render with `QListView`, and I choose to use `QListView` because the items are dynamically added and removed when the program is running. Is it possible to render these items as a queue of squares with width proportional to `item.x` where `x` is an integer member of the item? Should I subclass `QListView` or use delegate for the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You always use a delegate if you want to change how the items will be rendered in an item view. So yes, use a custom delegate for the rendering.

Comment: Can you show me some example code on this? All I can find is the StarDelegate and SpinBoxDelegate which is used for editor of text data.

Comment: My guess is I should override the `paint` method, but is it possible to put the squares representing the data into a layout?

Comment: You can paint whatever you want using the delegate. There are tons of delegates out there, here's a simple one: https://github.com/KDE/kate/blob/32d07734bcdda6e228d82b539185695150bdae10/apps/lib/filehistorywidget.cpp#L152 it paints a list of commits in a list and changes the height of the row to be a lot bigger